# Why isn't this jQuery firing on click? (w/ radio buttons)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, click, radio-button

```
function showHideSoldTo() {
    if ($("#radio-text-sold-to").prop("checked")) {
        $("#select-sold-to").hide();
        $("#text-sold-to").show();
    } else if ($("#radio-select-sold-to").prop("checked")) {
        $("#text-sold-to").hide();
        $("#select-sold-to").show();
    }
}

$("#radio-text-sold-to").click(showHideSoldTo());
$("#radio-select-sold-to").click(showHideSoldTo());
```

All this is inside a document ready wrapper.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Please include your HTML

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the () from the function names in the click call. So..

```
$("#radio-text-sold-to").click(showHideSoldTo);
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the () from the function names in the click call

just try like

```
$("#radio-text-sold-to").click(showHideSoldTo);
$("#radio-select-sold-to").click(showHideSoldTo);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the value you pass to the `.click()` method it's supposed to be a function value but instead you are invoking the function and as a result passing the return value of that function (which is equal to `undefined`)

the fix is simple you need to remove the `()` in these two lines

```
$("#radio-text-sold-to").click(showHideSoldTo());
$("#radio-select-sold-to").click(showHideSoldTo());
```

So they become

```
$("#radio-text-sold-to").click(showHideSoldTo);
$("#radio-select-sold-to").click(showHideSoldTo);
```

in javascript any identifier identifies a value. That value might be a simple value such as an integer or it might be a more complex object and as is the case with the value you pass as a callback or event handler it might be a function value.

These two lines of code are basically the same

```
function myFoo() {}
var myFoo = function() {}
```

and in the latter it's explicit that the right hand side is assigned to the left hand side. Ie that the function value is assigned to an identifier.

Comment: definitely more complete than my answer ;)